# How do I do a full text search in Sql Server 2008 where the data contains multiple languages?

Tags: sql-server, localization, full-text-search, collation

I have a database table in Sql Server 2008 R2 which contains data stored in multiple languages including English, Swedish, Hungarian and German.

The table uses the Latin1_General_CI_AS collation. The full text catalog has the table assigned to it with an index on the multi-language column.

I have two problems:

- In the catalog properties, a language has to be specified for word breaks. This is currently set to English. How do I get it to use multiple languages for word breaks?
- Hungarian is not even available in the list of languages that can be selected for word breaks. How do I configure the full text search to search Hungarian text?

Each row in the table contains only a single language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft, sys.fulltext_languages, Hungarian is not a supported language for Full Text Search.

The full list of supported languages is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176076.aspx

It also appears that you are going to have to choose one language or another:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2008/11/06/best-practices-for-integrated-full-text-search-ifts-in-sql-2008.aspx

> Handling multiple languages in a
>   single document is a hard problem. 
>   Which word breaker do you use to shred
>   the original document, and which
>   language are you going to specify for
>   the query?  For example, if you have a
>   document with Korean and English and
>   you use the Korean word breaker to
>   process the document, then if you
>   search the document for English words
>   it will only find the exact words and
>   not any other forms of the words (like
>   ing and s).